# Insert contact directly to my phone from a qr code

Tags: command, qr-code, contacts

Do anybody know how can I insert a contact to my phone just by scanning it's qr code? I mean is there any command or something which I can put before the contact detail while generating a qr code which will automatically add that contact to my phone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the vCard specification: [RFC 2426](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426.txt)

The data in the QR code needs to start with `BEGIN:VCARD` and prefixes such as `FN`, `TEL` and `EMAIL` are used to identify name, telephone, etc. And of course, whatever app you use to scan the bar code needs to handle vCards.

Example:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:John Doe
TEL:888-555-1234
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:johndoe@gmail.com
END:VCARD
```

Comment: I already vcard's structure for qr code generation...what I need is automation...I mean contact should be automatically save in the phone book as soon as it is scanned via the qr code

Comment: You need an app that looks for the VCARD format. If you are using an Android phone, you can download 'Barcode Scanner' by 'ZXing Team'. It gives you an 'Add Contact' option when you scan a QR code VCARD.

Comment: Is not there any command or code something for this...so that I can add the command and it works...